# Attendance using smartphone hotspot

Tags: android, ios, wireless, time-and-attendance

I wanted to build an attendance app (preferably iOS and android) where one phone shares hotspot. Devices connected to the hotspot will send the phone owner's name or ID that makes the hotspot phone recognize the phone users and adds one attendance point.

The hotspot phone will store the attendance online. It needs to be mobile app as the system will be used for an organisation that goes to different sites for every project.

*edit*
What are the technologies I should look into to make this application? Initially i was thinking of NFC but it requires devices to be close together. Connecting a wireless network is much more convenient imo. 
Thanks for your help

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow, besides describing what you want to do, you do not ask anything, or provide any code, there's no way to help you currently

Comment: Sorry for the lack of details. Was in a rush.

I'm only familiar coding websites and using native apps is something new to me.  Going to use this project for my Final Year Project and it is set to be used for a voluntary organisation to track their volunteers.

I have not coded anything for this project yet. But I need to know where to begin. The searches i made shows sniffing packets or rooting androids which isnt preferable. Anyway thank you for your input  :D

Answer (score 1):

Using **Network Service Discovery** you can achieve this. You need a wifi router to connect all the devices. One device will be a host and others will be a client.

Go through this link https://developer.android.com/training/connect-devices-wirelessly/nsd.html